# Akka stream sink map to BiConsumer

Tags: java, akka-stream

I have an akka stream sink and i want to map every input inside these sink to a BiConsumer, i declared the Sink as follows:

```
Sink<FactChangePayload, BiConsumer<String,FactChangePayload>> mapSink
```

i want to call the following consumer foreach element that arrives at the sink:

```
private BiConsumer<String,FactChangePayload> changePayloadBiConsumer=(string, factChangePayload) -> {
    System.out.println("Arrived:"+string+":for payload:"+factChangePayload);
};
```

i completed sink declaration as follows, but it failed to compile

```
printingSink=Sink.foreach(param -> changePayloadBiConsumer.accept("String",param));
```

compile error:

```
Wrong second argument type, found object, required FactChangePayload
```

any idea on how to do that?

Comment: There are a few things going on here that don't connect - the declaration of _mapSink_ isn't used in the rest of your example, so it's not relevant.  This suggests things may not be what you expect/want/need.

Comment: Add a type to _p_ in the _foreach_ call:  _foreach((FactChangePayload p) -> ..._